# Browser download file

Tags: java, javascript, html

Good morning in my timezone.

Those are simple questions , i just do not no if they have simple answers :)
I am developing a web app using JSP/Servlet framework.The user have the possibility to download a flat text file that i generate and send it to the browser.Snippet of pseudo-code:

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=interface.txt");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
response.write("data");
response.flush();
response.close();
```

My first question is, in IE brosers it appears a pop-up asking to the user, if he wants to 1)Open 2)Save 3)Cancel. Is there any way to know what decision the user took ?
If the answer to the above question is NO , how can i build a client-side Javascript script, to manage the download files , can anyone give some articles or good tutorial on the subject ?

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to know what decision the user took ?

No, there isn't. The browser has stopped sending data to the server at that point.

> How can i build a client-side Javascript script to manage the download files

Short of using bleeding edge features like local storage to fake it (and I really do mean fake it, you can't write to arbitrary parts of the visitor's file system), you can't. For obvious security reasons, web pages are not allowed to play with the file system.